# Parsing the same tags name for child nodes using DOM Parser Android

Tags: android, xml, parsing, listview, dom

I'm currently building an Application which reads an xml file from the following website: http://wx.toronto.ca/festevents.nsf/tpaview?readviewentries and then displays it in a listview with an image and in a single list view. The Problem i'm facing is that once parsed using the following code :

```
NodeList nodeList = document.getElementsByTagName("viewentry");
```

it only return the first child element from the xml file. The following is a partial copy of the xml file to get an idea:

```
<viewentries timestamp="20141204T225826,77Z" toplevelentries="486">
<viewentry position="1" unid="76D2D8314E365A2A85257DA4004B11B7" noteid="56C06" siblings="486">
<entrydata columnnumber="0" name="EventName">
<text>Learn To Skate Lessons</text>
</entrydata>
<entrydata columnnumber="1" name="Area">
<textlist>
<text>Central East</text>
<text>Southeast</text>
</textlist>
</entrydata>
<entrydata columnnumber="2" name="CategoryList">
<textlist>
<text>Family/Children</text>
<text>Sports</text>
</textlist>
</entrydata>
<entrydata columnnumber="3" name="PresentedByOrgName">
<text/>
</entrydata>
<entrydata columnnumber="4" name="Image">
<text>
http://wx.toronto.ca/festevents.nsf/all/76D2D8314E365A2A85257DA4004B11B7/$File/learntoskate.jpg
</text>
</entrydata>
</viewentry>
```

The following is my Android Code...I have tested my singleListview and my imageloader than they both work.

MainActivity

```
public class TorontourismActivity extends Activity{

    ListView listView;
    ListViewAdapter adapter;
    ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> arrayList;
    static String Event = "text";
    static String Area = "text";
    static String Category = "textlist";
    static String Presented = "entrydata";
    static String Image = "entrydata columnnumber=4 name=Image";    


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.listview_main); //View from the layout file in res folder
        new DownloadXMLFile().execute();
    }
    private class DownloadXMLFile extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>
    {
        @Override
        protected  void onPreExecute()
        {
            super.onPreExecute();
            progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(TorontourismActivity.this);
            progressDialog.setTitle("Torontourism the know it all for Toronto Events");
            progressDialog.setMessage("I'm loading....Give me a minute.");
            progressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            progressDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params)
        {
            arrayList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

            TorontourismParser parser = new TorontourismParser();
            String xml = parser.getXMLfromURL("http://wx.toronto.ca/festevents.nsf/tpaview?readviewentries");
            Document document = parser.getElements(xml);

            try
            {
                NodeList nodeList = document.getElementsByTagName("viewentry");

               for(int i =0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++)
               {
                   Element element = (Element) nodeList.item(i);
                   HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                       map.put(Event, parser.getValue(element, Event));
                       map.put(Area, parser.getValue(element, Area));
                       // map.put(Category, parser.getValue(element, Category));
                       map.put(Image, parser.getValue(element, Image));
                       /*map.put(ShowDate, parser.getValue(element, ShowDate));
                         map.put(BeginTime, parser.getValue(element, BeginTime));
                         map.put(EndShowDate, parser.getValue(element, EndShowDate));*/
                   System.out.println(Event);

                       arrayList.add(map);

               }
            } catch (Exception e)
              {
                 Log.i("Error in Torontourism Activity", e.getMessage());
                 e.printStackTrace();
              }
            return null;
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void arguments)
        {
            listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
            adapter = new ListViewAdapter(TorontourismActivity.this, arrayList);
            listView.setAdapter(adapter);
            progressDialog.dismiss();
        }

    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_torontourism, menu);
        return true;
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

DOM Parser

```
public class TorontourismParser {

    static final String FesEventURL = "http://wx.toronto.ca/festevents.nsf/tpaview?readviewentries";

     //constructor
    public TorontourismParser()
    {

    }

    //open a HTTP Connection

    public String getXMLfromURL(String urlString)
    {
        String xmlfile = null;
        try {
            DefaultHttpClient defaultHttpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(urlString);

            HttpResponse httpResponse = defaultHttpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            xmlfile = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);

        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return xmlfile;
    }

    public Document getElements(String xml)
    {
        Document document = null;
        DocumentBuilderFactory documentBuilderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        try {
            DocumentBuilder documentBuilder = documentBuilderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();

            InputSource inputSource = new InputSource();
            inputSource.setCharacterStream(new StringReader(xml));
            document = documentBuilder.parse(inputSource);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Error in Parser file", e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return document;
    }

    public final String getElements(Node node)
    {
        Node element;
        StringBuilder value = new StringBuilder();
        if(node != null)
        {
            if(node.hasChildNodes())
            {
                for(element = node.getFirstChild(); element != null;
                    element = element.getNextSibling())
                {
                        if (element.getNodeType() == Node.TEXT_NODE)
                        {
                            value.append(element.getNodeValue());
                        }
                }
            }
        }
        return value.toString();
    }

    public String getValue(Element element, String string) {
        NodeList nodeList = element.getElementsByTagName(string);

        return this.getElements(nodeList.item(0));

    }


}
```

ListViewAdapter

```
    public class ListViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

        Context context;
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
        ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> xmldata;
        ImageLoader imageLoader;
        HashMap<String,String> hashMap = new HashMap<String, String>();

        public ListViewAdapter(Context context,ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> arrayList)
        {
            this.context = context;
            xmldata = arrayList;
            imageLoader = new ImageLoader(context);

        }
        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return xmldata.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return 0;
        }


        public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            TextView Event;
            TextView Area;
            TextView Category;
            TextView Presented;
            ImageView Image;

            layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

            View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_item, parent, false);
            hashMap = xmldata.get(position);

            Event = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.Event);
            Area = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.Area);
            //Category = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.Category);
            //Presented = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.Presented);

            Image = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.Image);

            Event.setText(hashMap.get(TorontourismActivity.Event));
            Area.setText(hashMap.get(TorontourismActivity.Area));
            //Category.setText(hashMap.get(TorontourismActivity.Category));
            // Presented.setText(hashMap.get(TorontourismActivity.Presented));

            imageLoader.DisplayImage(hashMap.get(TorontourismActivity.Image),Image);

            Log.i("Event:", hashMap.get(TorontourismActivity.Event));

            view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view1) {
                    hashMap = xmldata.get(position);
                    Intent intent = new Intent(context,SingleItemView.class);

                    intent.putExtra("Event", hashMap.get(TorontourismActivity.Event));
                    intent.putExtra("Area", hashMap.get(TorontourismActivity.Area));
                   //  intent.putExtra("Category", hashMap.get(TorontourismActivity.Category));
                    //intent.putExtra("Presented", hashMap.get(TorontourismActivity.Presented));
                    intent.putExtra("Image", hashMap.get(TorontourismActivity.Event));

                    context.startActivity(intent);
                }

            });

            return view;
        }
    }

Single Item viewer

public class SingleItemView extends Activity {
    String Event;
    String Area;
    String Presented;
    String Category;
    String Image;
    ImageLoader imageLoader = new ImageLoader(this);

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle saveInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(saveInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.singleitemview);

        Intent intent = getIntent();

        Event = intent.getStringExtra("Event");
        Area = intent.getStringExtra("Area");
       //Presented = intent.getStringExtra("Presented");
       // Category = intent.getStringExtra("Category");
        Image = intent.getStringExtra("Image");

        TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Event);
        //TextView textView1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Area);
        //TextView textView2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Presented);
        //TextView textView3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Category);

        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.Image);

        textView.setText(Event);
        //textView1.setText(Area);
        //textView2.setText(Presented);
        //textView3.setText(Category);

        imageLoader.DisplayImage(Image, imageView);
    }

}
```

Image Loader

```
public class ImageLoader {

    MemoryCache memoryCache = new MemoryCache();
    FileCache fileCache;

    private Map<ImageView, String> imageViewStringMap
            = Collections.synchronizedMap(new WeakHashMap<ImageView, String>());
    ExecutorService executorService;
    Handler handler = new Handler();

    public ImageLoader(Context context) {
        fileCache = new FileCache(context);
        executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);
    }

    final int NoImage_Id = R.drawable.temp_img;

    public void DisplayImage(String url, ImageView imageView) {
        imageViewStringMap.put(imageView, url);
        Bitmap bitmap = memoryCache.get(url);
        if (bitmap != null) {
            imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        } else {
            queuePhoto(url, imageView);
            //imageView.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable());
           // imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.temp_img);
        }
    }

    private void queuePhoto(String url, ImageView imageView)
    {
        PhotoToLoad photoToLoad = new PhotoToLoad(url,imageView);
        executorService.submit(new PhotoLoader(photoToLoad));
    }

    private Bitmap getBitmap(String url) {
        File file = fileCache.getFile(url);

        Bitmap bitmap = decodeFile(file);
        if (bitmap != null)
            return bitmap;

        try {
            Bitmap bitmap1 = null;
            URL imageurl = new URL(url);
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) imageurl.openConnection();
            connection.setConnectTimeout(30000);
            connection.setReadTimeout(30000);
            connection.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);
            InputStream inputStream = connection.getInputStream();
            OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
            Utils.CopyStream(inputStream, outputStream);
            outputStream.close();
            connection.disconnect();
            bitmap = decodeFile(file);
            return bitmap;

        } catch (Throwable ex) {
            if (ex instanceof OutOfMemoryError)
                memoryCache.clear();
            return null;
        }
    }


    private Bitmap decodeFile(File file) {
        try {
            BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
            FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
            BitmapFactory.decodeStream(fileInputStream, null, options);
            fileInputStream.close();

            final int Size = 1000;
            int width_temp = options.outWidth, height_temp = options.outHeight;
            int scale = 1;
            while (true) {
                if (width_temp / 2 < Size || height_temp / 2 < Size)
                    break;
                width_temp /= 2;
                height_temp /= 2;
                scale *= 2;

            }

            BitmapFactory.Options options1 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            options1.inSampleSize = scale;
            FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream, null, options1);
            inputStream.close();
            return bitmap;
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    private class PhotoToLoad
    {
        public String url;
        public ImageView imageView;

        public PhotoToLoad(String uri, ImageView ImView)
        {
            url = uri;
            imageView = ImView;
        }
    }
    class PhotoLoader implements Runnable
    {
        PhotoToLoad photoToLoad;

        PhotoLoader(PhotoToLoad photoToLoad){
            this.photoToLoad = photoToLoad;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try{
                if(ImageViewReused(photoToLoad))
                    return;
                Bitmap bitmap = getBitmap(photoToLoad.url);
                memoryCache.put(photoToLoad.url, bitmap);
                if(ImageViewReused(photoToLoad))
                    return;
                BitmapDisplayer bitmapDisplayer = new BitmapDisplayer(bitmap,photoToLoad);
                handler.post(bitmapDisplayer);
            } catch (Throwable throwable){
                throwable.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }

    boolean ImageViewReused(PhotoToLoad photoToLoad)
    {
        String string = imageViewStringMap.get(photoToLoad.imageView);
        if(string == null || !string.equals(photoToLoad.url))
            return true;
        return false;
    }

    class BitmapDisplayer implements Runnable
    {
        Bitmap bitmap;
        PhotoToLoad photoToLoad;

        public BitmapDisplayer(Bitmap bitmap1, PhotoToLoad photoToLoad1)
        {
            bitmap = bitmap1;
            photoToLoad = photoToLoad1;
        }

        public void run() {
            if(ImageViewReused(photoToLoad))
                return;
            if(bitmap != null){
                photoToLoad.imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            }else{
                //photoToLoad.imageView.setImageResource(NoImage_Id);
            }

        }
    }

    public void clearCache()
    {
        memoryCache.clear();
        fileCache.clear();
    }
}
```

Any help is appreciated. From what i believe the problem lies inside the parser file. Other than that please help me.

Thank you!

Comment: have you check nodeList.getLength() ?

Comment: length is working fine. Whenever the tag is sent into the 'getvalue' method it only returns the first child note. if i change the following code : "NodeList nodeList = document.getElementsByTagName("viewentry");" to NodeList nodeList = document.getElementsByTagName("entrydata"); it displays all the nodes but in a different textview for each node.